# is there any r function for finding the element in a vector?

Tags: math, logic

Is there any r function for finding the element in a vector?

I have tried solving the question but getting problem in the vector concept regarding R.

Comment: [which](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html) or [match](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) should help. Can't test now, please write an answer after testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` if you want the first one and `which` if you want to get all positions. A nice example for your problem is: https://statisticsglobe.com/r-find-index-of-element-in-vector